# China visa duration is random for me

Tags: visas, china

I am a Greek citizen and I have traveled 4 times to China for business last year. The first time the embassy gave me a visa for 1 month, the second time for 3 months, the third time for 1 month and now the 4th time for 3 months.

My colleague got a 1 year visa with multiple entries from their second application. I asked every time for a visa with a maximum duration.

It might be a stupid question but, do they assign visas randomly ? :P

Comment: Note that Chinese visa durations can be influenced by internal political matters and by the length of time you wish to stay.

Answer (score 2):

Your colleague received a multiple-entry most probably because *he asked for it*... When you apply for a Chinese visa, you have to specify how many entries you would like. If you don't check the box that says multiple entry, you won't get it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But as i mentioned before i ask every time for the maximum duration.

Comment: Do you realize there is a difference between _maximum duration_ and _multiple entry_?